# RDLC footer and dynamic visibility

Tags: dynamic, textbox, rdlc, hidden, footer

tldr; Hide the left UI component on the footer and the right component moves over to the center.

I have a .rdlc file that I'm modifying in Visual Studio 2010 (and, sometimes, in Notepad++, as well). This particular report has a footer with two text boxes. The left side textbox contains information that is only sometimes relevant. When it is not relevant, it gets hidden. The right side textbox contains a page number.

So long as the left textbox is visible, everything is fine. However, when I hide the left textbox, the resulting output has the right textbox shifted over to the middle.

I don't want my page number shifted to the middle. How do I prevent this? I tried handling it with a table stretched all across the footer, but the footer apparently won't allow a table to be contained.

Comment: I ended up just creating a duplicate textbox to the one I was hiding and showing it when the original was hidden. This new one just contains a bunch of spaces rather than text. Kludgy, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, nobody has any better ideas, so I'm going to say that my comment above is the answer:

"I ended up just creating a duplicate textbox to the one I was hiding and showing it when the original was hidden. This new one just contains a bunch of spaces rather than text. Kludgy, but it worked."

Answer (score 0):

:)

I had the same issue. I just solved the issue be creating another Textbox and changed the hidden formula to vice versa.

Existing Text box (Moving) : =IIF(Parameters!PM_ReportType.Value = "ShowDiscrepancy",TRUE,FALSE)

Duplicate Text box Hide Formula = =IIF(Parameters!PM_ReportType.Value = "ShowDiscrepancy",FALSE,TRUE)

[TB Moved to Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqtfH.jpg)

[Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDCxl.jpg)

[Adjust the Hide formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YISon.jpg)